# symfony - creating database with doctrine

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

let say, my database name = television
everytime I try to craate database in CLEAN symfony project (I try version 2.3 or 2.5) for developer mode, it still create database "television" .. when I try to create database for production mode, it's trying to make database with same name "television"

in developer mode it should create database "television_dev",  not "television"

I had one cloned project (sylius), and in this project creating databases works fine ... I try to make sure, I have all bundles same (I mean doctrine versions), but it still not working

what am I doing wrong ? what should I config ?

Comment: Sylius is not Symfony, even if is based on SF project. Of course if you have configured SF with db_name = television, it will always create a db named "television". If you want to change it, simply change configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `app/config/config_dev.yml` add:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname:   %database_name%_dev
```

then you case use this command to create the db

`php app/console doctrine:database:create`

based on your environment either you will have `television` or `television_dev`

Comment: thanks .. this solved the probllem ... I overlooked it